# How to use data variable inside another data variable vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use data variable inside another data variable, but when I console it shows `undefined`. I'm trying to switch checkbox with setting data value `true` and `false`. My code is below,

```
data() {
        return {
            roleCreate:true,
            rows:[
              {
              id:1,
              type:0,
              create: `<label class="switch switch-primary mr-3">
                                <input type="checkbox"  ${this.roleCreate && 'checked'}>
                                <span class="slider"></span>
                            </label>`,
              }
            ]
       }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: why would you want to use a data variable instead of a normal template or a computed property?

Comment: @thks173 Sorry I didn't know how to use it, I'm new to vuejs. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the `rows` property is not dynamic.

The `HTML` code belongs to the template and the `javascript` code belongs to the script.

Try to be modularized your code.

If `rows` is a dynamic property you can use `v-for`

```js
data() {
    return {
        roleCreate:true
   }
}
```

```html
<label class="switch switch-primary mr-3">
    <input v-if="roleCreate" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label>
```